# ANDROID STUDIO: this project is not a gradle-based project

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, cs50

I have downloaded this source code https://cdn.cs50.net/2019/fall/tracks/android/pokedex/pokedex.zip

When I hit "sync project with gradle files", it says that this project is not a gradle based project.

I would be very thankful if someone can help me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you open the project from its root directory. i.e. the directory which contains the top level `build.gradle` file.

The missing top level gradle file is what causes this error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to android studio. How do I make sure I'm opening from the root directory?

Comment: The root directory is the directory in which your build.gradle lies. Go to `File > Open...` and open the project from the pokedex folder (in this case) not the app directory.